# How to develop a Rails app while in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I'm a complete beginner and really couldn't find any info on this. So let's assume that I built an app and published it live on a virtual server.

My question is: let's say that I need to make tweaks to the live app and I need to insert some new code and to install some new gems.... how the process looks for this and what tools are being used? 
My biggest concern is not to mess up the app while editing it in production, as also want it to stay live while I'm developing it..

Any references are also appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You would not edit an app that is in production. You would edit your development version. And once that is working, you would deploy that working version to production.

Comment: So basically to overwrite existing files? But then the live app will be down for some time?

Comment: No not overwriting. Normally (for example with a tool like capistrano) you would upload your new version into another folder next to the existing version. Then you would symlink that new folder to your app servers root and restart the app (what might take a few seconds).

Comment: this depends in the process you use for deploying, you can have multiple ruby processes that go down gradually to reload the new codebase, take a look at this article for example that uses (puma, foreman and capistrano) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-zero-downtime-rails-deploys-using-puma-and-foreman

Comment: As @spickermann said, you do code updates in development. Once that is done, there are tools for zero-down-time deployment, for eg. capistrano supports it. So that none of your users wait till site is for maintainance

Comment: thank you all! it's really helpful. I got an idea now :)

Comment: All the comments already have it, just to summarize: You have to study **deployment process** using any tool like capistrano, puppet, ansible or others. So as not to stop you application have a look at **zero downtime deployment**